# Issue with dry run for a short algorithm (recursion)

Tags: java, algorithm, recursion

```
public class Algo{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        System.out.println(bar(4));
    }
    static int bar(int n){
        if(n==0 || n==1){
            return 1;
        }else{
            return n-bar(n-1);
        }
    }
}
```

So here is what I believe the code above does:

```
n=4: 4-(4-1) = 4-3 = 1
n=3: 1-(3-1) = 1-2 = -1
n=2: -1-(2-1) = -1-1 = -2
n=1: Now we get into the if-statement, this basically means that bar(1) = 1, so in the end we have that -2-1 = -3
```

But when I compile and run it, I get a different output and I don't understand why..?

```
Output: 2
```

I tried another algorithm very similar to this one (just with multiplication sign aka faculty) and with this dry run it has worked. But it doesn't seem to work for this algorithm.

Comment: The first iteration is not `4-(4-1)`. It's `4-(3-(2-1))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how its computing:

```
bar(4) = 
4 - bar(3) = 
4 - (3 - bar(2)) = 
4 - (3 - (2 - bar(1))) = 
4 - (3 - (2 - 1))) 
4 - 3 + 2 - 1 = 
2
```

Comment: Awesome, with your notation i was able to understand what the code does in detail, thank you! :) and also thanks for every other answer, really much appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

Given that the code recurses to `n-1`, it's easier if you consider the result in order of increasing `n`, since you can simply substitute in the result from the previous row.

```
n    working  result
====================
0    (by def) 1
1    (by def) 1
2    2-1      1
3    3-1      2
4    4-2      2
```

Comment: Ooh, so with the exception of `0`, it's essentially `(n + 1) / 2`

Answer (score 1):

```
 bar(4) = 4 - bar(3) = 4 - 2 = 2
 bar(3) = 3 - bar(2) = 3 - 1 = 2
 bar(2) = 2 - bar(1) = 2 - 1 = 1
 bar(1) = 1
```